# Boostrap validator 1000Hz v0_11_9 more custom validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone i want to make more custom validation
in the form i have two date and i want to make custom validation to each 
one
the first just check if the date is not fall on weekend
the second have this validation too but plus check if this is higher then 
the first one.

```
So the problem is somebody know a syntax to make two custom validation?? 
:D pls
//check if the day falls on the weekend
function isWeekend(d, m){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(m-1, d);
    var n = date.getDay();
    return n;
}

//this part where i want to make two custom validation
$('form[data-toggle="validator"]').validator({
    custom: {
        nextpay_day: function($el) {
            var n_d = $('#nextpay_d').val();
            var n_m = $('#nextpay_m').val();
            var n = isWeekend(n_d, n_m);
            if (n == 6 || n == 0){
                return "This date falls on the weekend!";
            }
        },
        followpay_day: function($e1) {
            var date1 = new Date();
            var date2 = new Date();
            var n_d = $('#nextnextpay_d').val();
            var n_m = $('#nextnextpay_m').val();
            date2.setMonth(n_m-1, n_d);
            var n = isWeekend(n_d, n_m);
            if (n == 6 || n == 0){
                return "This date falls on the weekend!";
            }elseif(date2 <= date1){
                return "This date must be higher!";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This syntax is not good so somebody have a solution? :D
It is work if the custom have one data-tag like data-nextpay_d
But with two not work :(

Comment: maybe wrong the elseif part :o where i want to compare the two dates

Comment: OOOOOOh sorry this syntax is good just my elseif was wrong :D xD i use so many php
but in js this it is else if not elseif xD